# Meteor js - show template only for clicked item

Tags: meteor

I just need to have a "slideout" displayed for a clicked on list of items. For example, 20 items in the list, click on item 2, item 2 should display the slideout. Not sure why I'm failing here, but when I click, the slideout template displays across all 20 items. Perhaps its the each loop?

HTML:

```
{{#each wantJobs}}
  <div id="bidelement" class="bidelement">
   {{#if clickedBidElement}}
    {{>bidelementslideout}}
   {{/if}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

And my js with helpers and reactive var:

OnCreated:

```
this.clickedBidElement = new ReactiveVar;
this.clickedBidElement.set(false);
```

Helper for clickedBidElement check:

```
clickedBidElement : function() {
  return Template.instance().clickedBidElement.get();
}
```

Click event:

```
'click .bidelementinfocontainer' : function(e,template) {
   if (template.clickedBidElement.get() == false) {
   template.clickedBidElement.set(true);
   }
 }
```

What am I missing here thats causing all "Bid Elements" to draw a slideout when I click on only one? Thanks.

Comment: Your `clickBidElement` helper function merely returns `true` or `false`, not the id of the item the person clicked on. So, when you set the `ReactiveVar` to `true` it's going to return `true` for every item in the `#each` loop. Find some key value you can use to compare in your helper function and set the reactive var to that in your click handler.

Comment: Got it working now thank you - by adding an _id to the reactive var, which gets captured and displays on the right element. Thanks!